# Does rails HireFire support Queues?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, queue, delayed-job

Background:
I have 50 clients. (for example) they have their data partitioned into 50 different schemas in postgresql.
I feel it's a good idea to keep their processing as separate as possible, so I think putting their DJ's into different queues is a good idea, At least grouping them based on their load, into different queues (because I have a limit on the number of workers)

If Client_A has 10 large actions in the queue, Client_B shouldn't have to wait for them to be done, to send an email.

DJ supports queue's based workers.  I could be wrong, but I don't see a way to set queues in the [hirefire](https://github.com/meskyanichi/hirefire#readme) paradigm.
Does anyone know how to setup-[hirefire](https://github.com/meskyanichi/hirefire#readme) to run on a given queue?

I see more issues coming, but I'll ignore them for now :)

Comment: Could you please show us what hirefire is? It's the first time I've heard of it.

Comment: Also, have you considered switching to something like Resque which does support multiple queues?

Comment: Actually Delayed_job's got queues now too :)  The problem with Resque is that you stop the worker and all the popped tasks go poof. DJ just changes the status on started jobs.

Comment: @RyanBigg Added link to hirefire.

Comment: Oh.. also though Resque does do things in Queues.. it's a bit flawed.. When you start a worker with 3 queues stipulated, that is how they're prioritized.. If you have 3 things in que B and add to queA then the next task picked up will be the one in queA, even though queB tasks were in there first.